# jQuery Closest Relative

Tags: jquery, xml

I encountered this question in a "famous" online interviewing website:

> The following XML represents a family tree:

```
<James>
     <Dave></Dave>
     <Mike></Mike>
     <Sarah></Sarah> 
</James>
```

> Implement the closestRelative function so that it returns the parent's closest relative whose name matches the
>   relativeName and obays the following rules:
>
> The parent parameter is a jQuery selector of which the closest
>   relative will be a descendant. Each member of the family, including
>   children, may also be a parent to one or more children. Children are
>   more closely related to the parent than grandchildren. If several
>   children in the same generation have the same name then the first
>   child in the tree is considered the closer. If no matching relative is
>   found the function should return an empty jQuery object. For example,
>   closestRelative($('James'), 'Mike') should return the jquery object
>   wrapping `<Mike></Mike>`.
>
> ECMAScript 5.1, jQuery v3.1.1 (available as $)

Because of jQuery's `find` search depth first, rather than breadth first as stated on the hints of the question; my first approach was wrong. Then I wrote a recursive function for *"breadth find"* as below:

```
function closestRelative(parent, relativeName) {
  firstLevel = $(parent).children();
  if (firstLevel.length) {
    result = $(firstLevel).filter(relativeName);
    if (result) {
      return result.first();
    } else {
      closestRelative(firstLevel, relativeName);
    }
  } else {
    return $([]);
  }

}
```

The results of the test cases:

> Example case: Correct answer
>     Several generations: Wrong answer
>     Children with the same name: Wrong answer

I couldn't find a solution which pass the all 3 test cases and I don't know what I'm missing because I'm already searching for several generations and returning the first child of encountered family members array. What is wrong with code and how can I test this function against the xml and get `<Mike></Mike>` as result?

```
var xml = $.parseXML("<James><Dave></Dave><Mike></Mike><Sarah></Sarah></James>");
console.log(closestRelative($(xml).children()[0], 'Mike')[0].outerHTML); //Something is wrong here
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ros9cdvg/

Comment: I've never heard of an `outerText()` function in jQuery, so that console.log will not work...

Comment: You could use the jQuery function siblings(), or if you also want to search in depth closest().

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I replaced it with outerHTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following answer is tested to give 100%

```
function closestRelative(parent, relativeName) {
   result = $(parent).find(relativeName);
   if (result.length === 1) {
      return result;
  } else if(result.length > 1) {
      //identify the lowest element by getting the node level index
      // difference between the parent and the child, Use the lowest of that 
      // to return the response  
      var lowest = 0;
      var lowestidx = 0;
      $(result).each(function(idx, item) {
        if(idx===0) {
          lowest = $(item).parents().index(parent);
        }
        else {
             if ($(item).parents().index(parent) < lowest) {
                lowestidx = idx;
               lowest = $(item).parents().index(parent);
             }
           }
      });
      return $([result[lowestidx]]);
  }
  else {
    return $([]);
  }
}
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/YasirKamdar/pen/zRLNPb

Answer (score 0):

This bit:

```
if (result) {
  return result.first();
} else {
  closestRelative(firstLevel, relativeName);
}
```

Needs to be:

```
if (result.length) {
  return result.first();
} else {
  return closestRelative(firstLevel, relativeName);
}
```

Then you will pass all three test cases.

@Hamzaouiii: Your code will not work correctly with the case `<James><Dave><Mike></Mike></Dave><Mike></Mike><Sarah></Sarah></James>` where you will return the grandchild "Mike" and not the child.

That's why the OP's solution checks the child level first and then uses recursion to move down to the next generation.